# Is the cell size dependent on the number of features for the Euclidean Distance tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, distance, nodata, cell-size

I have attempted to run the Euclidean Distance tool, using ArcMap 10.5.1, on a feature class of 50 points (hospitals), but I received an invisible output. Using 'Identify' I get 'NoData' for the pixel values.

Is the cell size dependent on or limited by the number of features in the input FC?

What I think is more likely is the output cell size is causing the output issues. I want to do a Weighted Sum on my raster data, and I am trying to make the cell sizes in Euclidean Distance consistent for the raster math. I have grocery store and hospital FCs as separate inputs/outputs. I don't understand why this> is happening, but the default output cell sizes are drastically different for these two point FC inputs. One is 000s, and the other is 0.0000000 -E^3. I have tried to find an output cell size that works for both but haven't been successful (hospitals output raster is invisible/NoData).

Comment: "attempted to run the Euclidean Distance tool" what software????

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.5.1

Comment: What are the (width and height) of the extent of your points feature?

Comment: You havent mentioned if the two datasets have the same coordinate systems. Check that, also try and use a measured system ie: UTM or the likes).

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the help file for this tool, especially the [syntax](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/euclidean-distance.htm#GUID-BAE61728-58E6-458F-9D0B-CA0E261B5AC4) section you can see that you can specify the cell size. So why not set it? Sounds like you are not setting this obvious parameter and ArcMap is having to do a best guess based upon the extents of the input data.  You do not describe what coordinate system your input features are. Try zooming to the layer's extent, does one of them zoom to your entire country/world? You mention lots of zeros so my gut feeling that they are in decimal degrees when really you should be in a coordinate system in metres/feet.